# An external USB fax modem (unknown brand) is not working in Windows 10

Tags: usb, modem, fax

I installed 56k USB fax modem in Windows 10 successfully. The problem is when I restart the computer I need to unplug then plug again USB fax modem to work. I had disabled power saving for USB.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The issue is probably unrelated to the hardware (peripherals) or the OS themselves. Typically this situations are related with the hardware initialization and that depends mostly on the motherboard's firmware (BIOS or UEFI) so looking for and installing an update should be the first step. If modern UEFI try disabling Fast Boot as well.

Comment: @changauto - It seems likely to me that the OS should be able to recan the USB when its up. I would think this is a bad driver. If plugging and unplugging the USB drive works, why is the UEFI/BIOS to blame?